# 'PUT' Request to database is adding wrong value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, fetch-api, put

I'm building a React app using Firebase Realtime Database. In my database I have a key whose value is an array of objects:

```
Database = {"hello":[
                     {"world":false},
                     {"mom":false},
                     {"sunsin4":true}
                    ]
           }
```

All I want to do is send a PUT request to toggle the value of a given object.
So, I have a event handler that takes as arguments the ID of the Database object, the index of the selected object, the key, and the value:

```
eventHandler(ID, index, key, keyValue){
```

I then create the new json object for the PUT request:

```js
let newObj = { [key]: !keyValue }
```

then I pass all of this to:

```js
this.props.toggle(newObj,ID, index)
```

this all gets sent to:

```
async function toggle(newObj, ID, index){
     await fetch(`https:.........firebasio.com/database/${ID}/hello/${index}.json`,{
     method: 'PUT',
     body: JSON.stringify(newOBJ),
     header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
```

the problem I'm having is that when my data reaches my database it's appending the word key to the end of my object key --> { world,**key** :true }
other than that it seems to work. What am I missing? I can't figure this out.

Comment: If you inspect the request in the browser developer tools, is the request body correct? or does it already have the `,key` appended? If the request looks OK on the browser, then you're doing something wrong in the server code

Comment: when I console.log(newObj) I just get [Object Object].

Comment: FYI, it's `headers` (plural). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

Comment: `{"sunsin4":true}` should be `{"bucksin4":true}`

Comment: well you're calling toggle with a string === `"[Object Object]"` - so that's another problem